# Passing data to a remote server

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

Using Kotlin, Retrofit and Coroutines, I have defined an interface to get data from a remote server and most importantly pass the id of a selected RecyclerView item back to the server.

```
interface CourseService {
    @GET("/mobile/feed/course_data.php")
    suspend fun getCourseData(@Query("pathName") pathName: String): Response<List<Course>>
}
```

Here, i get the id of the selected item from a RecyclerView from my MainFragment and store it in "selectedItem" variable.

```
override fun onPathItemClick(path: Path) {
    viewModel.selectedItem.value = path
    selectedItem= viewModel.selectedItem.value!!.path_id
    navController.navigate(R.id.action_mainFragment_to_courseFragment)
}
```

I pass the value of selected item to the getCourseData() function

```
class CourseRepository(val app: Application) {

    val courseData = MutableLiveData<List<Course>>()

    init {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            callWebService()
        }
    }

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun callWebService() {
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(WEB_SERVICE_URL).addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create()).build()
            val service = retrofit.create(CourseService::class.java)
            val serviceData = service.getCourseData(selectedItem).body() ?: emptyList()
            courseData.postValue(serviceData)
    }
}
```

But i get no results and it seems as though the value passed to getCourseData() function is null, but when checking the log is does have a value.

so if i give it a predefined value anywhere in my code like below, everything works completely fine

```
    selectedItem= "MOB001"
    val serviceData = service.getCourseData(selectedItem).body() ?: emptyList()
```

However, i cannot give it a fixed value prior to runtime because the value is retrieved when the user selects an item from a RecyclerView.

These are my multiple logs:

```
2020-05-01 13:56:30.431 23843-23843/ I/mylog: Main Fragment before item click: selectedItem = 
2020-05-01 13:56:37.757 23843-23843/ I/mylog: Main Fragment after item click: selectedItem = WEB001
2020-05-01 13:56:37.763 23843-23843/ I/mylog: Course Fragment onCreateView(): selectedItem = WEB001
2020-05-01 13:56:37.772 23843-23901/ I/mylog: Course Fragment CourseRepository: selectedItem = WEB001
```

How can i overcome this issue?

Comment: what happens when you use selectedItem? What is the error?

Comment: @codebrane, there is no error, but based on results, it looks like it is passed as null

Comment: @codebrane, if i predefine selectedItem = "WEB001" anywhere in my code, it works fine

Comment: that suggests selectedItem is null in courseFragment. The code doesn't seem to pass it to the fragment so callWebService gets selectedId as null

Comment: you're calling callWebService in init, which suggests selectedItem may not have been initialised by then. Adding selectedItem= "MOB001" directly before calling the service will fix it but the issue seems to be calling the service as soon as the class is instantiated and not waiting until selectedItem is set from the other fragment

Comment: @codebrane, i am logging the value of selectedItem in courseFragment and also right before i pass it, and both logs show it has a value

Comment: you could add a HttpLoggingInterceptor with HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY to the OkHttpClient to see what the call is sending to the server

Comment: @codebrane, you're absolutely right, but i am actually getting the value of Item selected from a previous fragment

Comment: it depends on the relationship between creating a new CourseRepository and when onPathItemClick runs. If CourseRepository is created before, then you'll get null for selectedItem

Comment: @codebrane, i am actually getting the selectedItem from a RecyclerView item in a prior fragment. Also if i log the selected item right before i pass it and it shows it does have a value.

Comment: I have edited the question and added my logs.

Comment: @codebrane, thank you a lot, i followed your suggestion to use HttpLoggingInterceptor with HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY ... and finally i solved my problem after 3 full days of headache

Answer (score 1):

You should call your `CourseRepository`'s suspend function `callWebService`  inside your `ViewModel`. Here is your repository:

```
class CourseRepository(val app: Application) {
    suspend fun callWebService(path: Path): List<Course> {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(WEB_SERVICE_URL).addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create()).build()
            val service = retrofit.create(CourseService::class.java)
            service.getCourseData(path.path_id).body() ?: emptyList()
        }
    }
}
```

Then you should call your repository function in your ViewModel as follows:

```
fun getCourseData(path: Path): LiveData<List<Course>> {
    val response = MutableLiveData<List<Course>>()
    viewModelScope.launch {
        response.postValue(repository.callWebService(path))
    }
    return response
}
```

Then call `viewModel. getCourseData(path)` from your `Activity` or `Fragment` or anywhere when you get valid `Path` value.

Don't forget to include `implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0"` to your gradle file.

Comment: Although i use a different way of working, you code did help me with solving another issue which was how to pass the path Id,  so thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be correct, however, it is highly possible that your RecyclerView is being populated the first time and and evertime you go back and choose another path it is being populated with the same data and view.

Therefore, your attentions should be focused on why the data is not being fetched again, which is the cause of the RecyclerView and Fragment holding on to the same first view.

Answer (score 0):

After days of thinking my code was wrong, it turned out that my RecyclerView adapter was loading the same view everytime i wen back to select a different path becuase my RecyclerView was being inflated in the onCreateView() function which is only called once only, when a fragment is inflated the first time.

```
class CourseFragment : Fragment(),
    CourseRecyclerAdapter.CourseItemListener {

    private lateinit var viewModel: CourseViewModel
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_course, container, false)
        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.courseRecyclerView)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.nav_host )
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(CourseViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.courseData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            val adapter =
                CourseRecyclerAdapter(
                    requireContext(),
                    it,
                    this
                )
            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        } )
        return view
    }

    override fun onCourseItemClick(course: Course) {
        viewModel.selectedCourse.value = course
        navController.navigate(R.id.action_courseFragment_to_detailFragment)
    }
}
```